# Impossible to be const-correct when combining data and it's lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, mutable

I've been looking at ways to combine a piece of data which will be accessed by multiple threads alongside the lock provisioned for thread-safety. I think I've got to a point where I don't think its possible to do this whilst maintaining const-correctness.

Take the following class for example:

```
template <typename TType, typename TMutex>
class basic_lockable_type
{

public:
    typedef TMutex lock_type;

public:
    template <typename... TArgs>
    explicit basic_lockable_type(TArgs&&... args)
        : TType(std::forward<TArgs...>(args)...) {}

    TType& data() { return data_; }
    const TType& data() const { return data_; }

    void lock() { mutex_.lock(); }
    void unlock() { mutex_.unlock(); }

private:
    TType           data_;
    mutable TMutex  mutex_;

};

typedef basic_lockable_type<std::vector<int>, std::mutex> vector_with_lock;
```

In this I try to combine the data and lock, marking `mutex_` as `mutable`. Unfortunately this isn't enough as I see it because when used, `vector_with_lock` would have to be marked as `mutable` in order for a read operation to be performed from a `const` function which isn't entirely correct (`data_` should be `mutable` from a const).

```
void print_values() const
{
    std::lock_guard<vector_with_lock> lock(values_);
    for(const int val : values_)
    {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
} 

vector_with_lock values_;
```

Can anyone see anyway around this such that const-correctness is maintained whilst combining data and lock? Also, have I made any incorrect assumptions here?

Comment: Make `lock` and `unlock` const? (Also, should it not be `std::lock_guard<vector_with_lock>`? Why did you make a new lockable for if you are not going to use it?)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Of course, marking these const will allow a non-mutable `vector_with_lock` instance call `lock` and `unlock`, yes?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes If you provide an answer explaining adding const qualifiers to `lock` and `unlock` I can accept that as an answer

Comment: I posted an answer suggesting a more encapsulated design instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I'd prefer a design where you don't have to lock manually, and the data is properly encapsulated in a way that you cannot actually access it without locking first.

One option is to have a friend function `apply` or something that does the locking, grabs the encapsulated data and passes it to a function object that is run with the lock held within it.

```
//! Applies a function to the contents of a locker_box
/*! Returns the function's result, if any */
template <typename Fun, typename T, typename BasicLockable>
ResultOf<Fun(T&)> apply(Fun&& fun, locker_box<T, BasicLockable>& box) {
    std::lock_guard<BasicLockable> lock(box.lock);
    return std::forward<Fun>(fun)(box.data);
}
//! Applies a function to the contents of a locker_box
/*! Returns the function's result, if any */
template <typename Fun, typename T, typename BasicLockable>
ResultOf<Fun(T const&)> apply(Fun&& fun, locker_box<T, BasicLockable> const& box) {
    std::lock_guard<BasicLockable> lock(box.lock);
    return std::forward<Fun>(fun)(box.data);
}
```

Usage then becomes:

```
void print_values() const
{
    apply([](std::vector<int> const& the_vector) {
        for(const int val : the_vector) {
            std::cout << val << std::endl;
        }
    }, values_);
}
```

Alternatively, you can abuse range-based for loop to properly scope the lock and extract the value as a "single" operation. All that is needed is the proper set of iterators<sup>1</sup>:

```
 for(auto&& the_vector : box.open()) {
    // lock is held in this scope
    // do our stuff normally
    for(const int val : the_vector) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
 }
```

I think an explanation is in order. The general idea is that `open()` returns a RAII handle that acquires the lock on construction and releases it upon destruction. The range-based for loop will ensure this temporary lives for as long as that loop executes. This gives the proper lock scope.

That RAII handle also provides `begin()` and `end()` iterators for a range with the single contained value. This is how we can get at the protected data. The range-based loop takes care of doing the dereferencing for us and binding it to the loop variable. Since the range is a singleton, the "loop" will actually always run exactly once.

The `box` should not provide any other way to get at the data, so that it actually enforces interlocked access.

Of course one can stow away a reference to the data once the box is open, in a way that the reference is available after the box closes. But this is for protecting against Murphy, not Machiavelli.

The construct looks weird, so I wouldn't blame anyone for not wanting it. One one hand I want to use this because the semantics are perfect, but on the other hand I don't want to because this is not what range-based for is for. On the gripping hand this range-RAII hybrid technique is rather generic and can be easily abused for other ends, but I will leave that to your imagination/nightmares ;) Use at your own discretion.

---

<sup>1</sup> Left as an exercise for the reader, but a short example of such a set of iterators can be found in my own [locker_box implementation](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/default/include/wheels/concurrency/locker_box.h%2B%2B).

Comment: O_o that `for` is rather abusive.

Comment: And I just noticed a bug in my implementation :S Ooops. Don't use that code at home, kids.

Comment: Is it still buggy? If so, for what reason?

Answer (score 4):

What do you understand by "const correct"?  Generally, I think that there is a consensus for logical const, which means that if the mutex isn't part of the logical (or observable) state of your object, there's nothing wrong with declaring it `mutable`, and using it even in const functions.

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, whether the mutex is locked or not is part of the observable state of the object -- you can observe it for example by accidentally creating a locking inversion.

That is a fundamental issue with self-locking objects, and I guess one aspect of it does relate to const-correctness.

Either you can change the "lockedness" of the object via a reference-to-const, or else you can't make synchronized accesses via reference-to-const. Pick one, presumably the first.

The alternative is to ensure that the object cannot be "observed" by the calling code while in a locked state, so that the lockedness isn't part of the observable state. But then there's no way for a caller to visit each element in their `vector_with_lock` as a single synchronized operation. As soon as you call the user's code with the lock held, they can write code containing a potential or guaranteed locking inversion, that "sees" whether the lock is held or not. So for collections this doesn't resolve the issue.